# Difference between Keras Layer output and input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm doing a transfer learning, and notice that there're no difference between:

```
letterModel = Model(inputs=trained.get_layer('input').output, outputs = output)
```

and

```
letterModel = Model(inputs=trained.input, outputs=output)
```

Is it true? I can't understand how the output of Input layer can be used as input of new model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption seems to be correct. `trained.get_layer('input').output` and `trained.input` are equal Tensors. To verify, I loaded a Keras `Model` object:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

1) Getting the first `Input` Layer from the model and printing its output tensor.

> Note: You used `model.get_layer( 'input' )` to get the input layer for
>   the model. I have used `model.layers[0]` for the same purpose.

```
>>> model.layers[0].output
<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 49152) dtype=float32>
```

2) Likewise, printing the `model` input tensor.

```
>>> model.input
[<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 49152) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(?, 49152) dtype=float32>]
```

> The model printed a list of two Tensors as the model has two `Input`
>   layers. As you can see the 1st Tensor is equal to the Tensor printed
>   in ( 1 ).

3) We can check this via a `Boolean` expression.

```
>>> model.input[0] == model.layers[0].output
True
```